# Компиляция PyQt5 проекта на macOS

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside2, pyside

Сделал простенькое приложение и хочу его собрать в один файл на macOS.[image: alh1mik_tool.py - это сам интерфейс, а main.py это скрипт к этому интерфейсу.]

alh1mik_tool.py - это сам интерфейс, а main.py это скрипт к этому интерфейсу.
Как же мне скомпилировать все эти 2 файла в одно приложение на macOS?

Comment: `pyinstaller --onfile main.py`

Comment: pyinstaller: error: unrecognized arguments: --onfile пишет

Comment: --onefile, у меня опечатка

Answer (score 1):

Установите модуль pyinstaller(pip install pyinstaller) и с помощью команды "pyinstaller --onefile main.py" в нужной директории скомпилируйте. Файл будет в папке "dist".